# jquery hasClass give the wrong result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to check if a toggle element has a specific class or not, and I don't see where the problem can comes from :

```
<div class="tog">
   <div id="1" class="toggle toggle-light on"></div>
</div>
<div class="tog">
   <div id="2" class="toggle toggle-light on"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

and in the js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myButton" ).on("click",function(){
        $('.tog').each(function(i, obj) {
            var s = "yes";
            if ($(this).children("div").hasClass('toggle-off')) {
                s = "no";
            }

            console.log($(this).children("div").attr('class'));
            console.log(obj.id+s);
        });
    });
```

Result (in Firebug console):

```
toggle toggle-light on
1 yes
toggle toggle-light on
2 yes
```

but if I switch off now the toggle :

- in the source code, the class becomes fine "toggle-off" (toggle becomes grey) : OK
- but I always get "toggle toggle-light on"

I don't understand at all... any idea?

Comment: Post the code that switch to "toggle-off".

Comment: How are you toggling off?

Comment: I use this plugin : https://github.com/simontabor/jquery-toggles, I probably do not use it correctly

Comment: This seems correct to me? It does not have the class 'toggle-off', and thus 's' does not get set to 'no'.

Comment: Yu should check for `! element.hasClass('active')` if you are using that plugin.

Comment: I tried with .hasClass('active') but it still doesn't work..

Comment: or does someone know a simplier way to use multiple toggles? it could be a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer :

```
$(".myButton" ).on("click",function(){
    $('.toggle').each(function(i, obj) {
        console.log($(this).data('toggles').active);
        //will show true or false depending the toggle is active or not
    });
 });
```